# Multiple video.js instances - Stop all playing instances

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

I use video.js to play my HTML5 video's. I know have multiple instances of the player in the same html-page. I use jQuery to show/hide the div's containing one of the instances:

```
$('.menulink').click(function ShowDivs() {
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).show().siblings().hide();    
});
```

The result of this is when you show/hide a div, the video keeps playing. I would like to add a a rule to my function so all the instances of the player, stop playing the video whenever you switch to the next video. Is this possible? All the instances have the same ID.

I found in the API-documentation to use myPlayer.pause();
but I can't seem to find out how exactly.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$('.menulink').click(function ShowDivs() {
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).show().siblings().hide().each(function () { _V_($(this).children('video').attr('id')).pause(); };    
});
```

**EDIT:** Or, more likely, this:

```
$('.menulink').click(function ShowDivs() {
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).show().siblings().hide().each(function () { _V_(this).pause(); };
});
```